# Is there any performance penalty building go program using -race flag?

Tags: go, build, concurrency

Hi I was wondering if there any performance penalty running a go program in production built using

```
go build -race
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read about it in the article post that describes the go race detector at https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector

Quoting from that article (the last paragraph) :

> ## Runtime Overhead
>
> The cost of race detection varies by program, but for a typical program, memory usage may increase by 5-10x and execution time by
> 2-20x.
>
> The race detector currently allocates an extra 8 bytes per defer and
> recover statement. Those extra allocations [are not recovered until the
> goroutine exits](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26813). This means that if you have a long-running goroutine
> that is periodically issuing defer and recover calls, the program
> memory usage may grow without bound. These memory allocations will not
> show up in the output of runtime.ReadMemStats or runtime/pprof.